# Remove all sub-directories and files except for one

Tags: linux, bash, cron, find

I have a folder structure as follows:

`/home/user/<individual_user>`

In some of the `<individual_user>` folders there is a `.bashrc` file that I want to keep, however I want to remove all files and folders under `/home/user/<individual_user>` except that `.bashrc` file. All other files and subdirectories under `<individual_user>` should be deleted. There is an undetermined number of `<individual_user>` folders.

I would prefer to execute this command as a one-liner under cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your edit, you can use:

```
find /home/user -mindepth 2 -not -path '*/.bashrc' -print
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, you can replace `-print` with `-delete` to make it:

```
find /home/user -mindepth 2 -not -path '*/.bashrc' -delete
```

Comment: My original post had an issue. It's been fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
find /home/user ! -name .bashrc -exec rm -rf {} +
```

For obvious reasons, I haven't tested it ;)

Comment: I don't get the "obvious reasons". It would be a lot more "obvious" that you had. And provided a working demo ideone.com or similar

Comment: 1. Create a lot of files 2. Test it 3. Profit

Comment: My original post had an issue. It's been fixed now.